# If fluorine and cerium ion have more oxidising power than KMnO4, why is KMnO4 more popularly used as an oxidising agent?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox

It is quite clear from the electrode potential values that $\ce{F2}$ and $\ce{Ce^{4+}}$ are better oxidizing agents that $\ce{KMnO4}$.

Comment: Have you considered price, safety, toxicity, stability to store..? Also, oxidizing agents are not interchangeable in many reactions - electrode potential is not the only important parameter when you want to prepare specific products.

Comment: Using $\ce{F2}$  instead of $\ce{KMnO4}$ is much like using a hand grenade to kill a mosquito.

Comment: KMnO4 you find in glass bottles in most chem labs. For a strong oxidising agent it's relatively non-toxic and won't inflame and destroy a good number of common materials too quickly, such as glass, metals and human beings. Fluorine will. Fluorine is nasty, very nasty, and no sane person uses it unless necessary. Ce4+ I don't know, but you do come across in labs at the undergrad level once in a while, and once even at school. My guess is that it is much more expensive then KMnO4.

Comment: Lanthanides are pretty expensive. There's a reason why there popularly called as ''rare earth metals".